# storing key value pairs in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, keyvaluepair

I have 2 arrays namely,

```
configdata = ["assignee", "shortDesc"];
ticketarray = ["Tom","testDesc"];
```

I want to store the values as a key value pair in another array, something like this:

```
ticketData = ["assignee":"Tom","shortDesc":"testDesc"];
```

Kindly note that the array values are dynamic, so I cannot hardcode them. 
Is there a way to do so? I am able to achieve the above said requirement but the length always shows 0. This is the code that I am using:

```
configdata.Incident_Field.forEach(function (k, i) {
   this[k] = ticketarray[i];
}, ticketData);
```

Comment: use objects! :-)

Comment: You can't have an *array* like that. (Asterisk, footnote, well, you can, but it's not what you think it is.) What you want is an *object* (`{assignee: 'Tom', ...}`).

Comment: You use an object for a key-value pair. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @deceze I'm not aware of that, what is it? EDIT: cf **well, you can, but it's not what you think it is.**

Comment: @Ivan Arrays are objects too and you can assign arbitrary properties to them…

Answer (score 1):

Other people have explained why your code did not work. I am providing another solution using `reduce`.

```
const configdata = ["assignee", "shortDesc"];
const ticketarray = ["Tom", "testDesc"];

let ticketData = configdata.reduce((result, value, index) => {
  result[value] = ticketarray[index];
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(ticketData);
```

Output:

```
{
    assignee: "Tom", 
    shortDesc: "testDesc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is not a valid structure in JavaScript:

> `ticketData = ["assignee":"Tom","shortDesc":"testDesc"];`

What you need is a [JavaScript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). The best you can do is:

1. Make sure both the array lengths are same.
2. Associate the key and value by creating a new object.
3. Use `Object.keys(obj).length` to determine the length.

Start with the following code:

```js
configdata = ["assignee", "shortDesc"];
ticketarray = ["Tom", "testDesc"];

if (configdata.length == ticketarray.length) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < configdata.length; i++)
    obj[configdata[i]] = ticketarray[i];
}

console.log("Final Object");
console.log(obj);
console.log("Object's Length: " + Object.keys(obj).length);
```

The above will give you an object of what you liked, a single variable with all the values:

```
{
  "assignee": "Tom",
  "shortDesc": "testDesc"
}
```